# JavaScript в среде разработки NetBeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, ide

Как добавить javascript в NetBeans IDE 6.8? Где скачать русификатор NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

Официальный сайт `NetBeans` русифицирован (не полностью, но много чего), при навигации по страницам каждый раз нужно менять язык вручную. Имеется неплохая русская [документация](http://netbeans.org/kb/index_ru.html). Для свободного скачивания доступна последняя версия [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) с русским интерфейсом.

PS: если скачаете нормальную версию, не нужно будет ничего добавлять и русифицировать, все работает из коробочки. `IDE` можно дополнять плагинами.

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте в EMACS howdoi-mode:

```
<M-x> package-install <RET> howdoi
```

Далее:

```
<M-x> howdoi-query <RET> how to add javascript to NetBeans
```